# Refactor Oxford Comma function (and other functions)

Tags: python, optimization, strings, formatting

I wrote a program that managed projects and created a set of SQL files for each project. In the logic, I have a few functions that, each time I look at them, I wonder if they could be written in a better way. They are pretty straight forward and compact, however I feel like there are better, more efficient ways of computing their results.

I would appreciate any comments on coding style or improvements (either in readability or performance) that you may have.

### Oxford Comma

This function takes a `list` as input then passes an [Oxford comma-separated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) string off to another function:

```
# >>> obj._format_missing_message(['a','b','c'])
# 'a, b, and c'
def _format_missing_message(self, missing): 
        length = len(missing)

        # Show the message if needed
        if length > 0:
            and_clause = '{} and '.format('' if length <= 2 else ',')
            message = and_clause.join([', '.join(missing[:-1]), missing[-1]])
            self._tab_pane.currentWidget().update_status(
                                            "Configs not found for: {}.".format(message))
```

### SQL 'LIKE' String Creator

This next function takes a `list` of string inputs then finds the SQL LIKE syntax that recognizes all of the list:

```
import difflib

# >>> create_sql_regex(['123','124','125'])
# '12%'
def create_sql_regex(ids):
    ''' Creates a SQL regex from a list of strings for use in LIKE statement '''
    longest_match = ''

    # Raise an error if there is only one item in the list as there needs to be at least two
    # items to create the regex.
    length = len(ids)
    if length <= 1:
        raise NotEnoughComparisonData(
                 'Not enough data to compare. Passed list length: {}'.format(length))

    # Create the SequenceMatcher and loop through each element in the list, comparing it and
    # the previous item.
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher()
    for item, next_item in zip(ids[:-1], ids[1:]):
        matcher.set_seqs(item, next_item)
        long_match = matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(item), 0, len(next_item))

        # If the match is shorter than the previous longest match or if we have not found
        # a match yet, store the match
        if long_match.size < len(longest_match) or longest_match == '':
            longest_match = item[long_match.a:long_match.a + long_match.size]

    # If not match was found, raise an error
    if longest_match == '':
        raise NoMatchFound('A match could not be found in this list: {0}'.format(ids))

    return '{}%'.format(longest_match)
```

### Count Duplicates

This function is the simplest of the three. It takes a `list` as input and returns a `hash` that holds the count of each unique item found in the `list`:

```
# >>> count_duplicates(['a','a','b'])
# {'a':2, 'b':1}
def count_duplicates(values):
    counts = {}

    for val in values:
        if val in counts:
            counts[val] += 1
        else:
            counts[val] = 1

    return counts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Oxford comma

Are these really your expected outcomes?

```
# for ['a']
Configs not found for:  and a.

# for ['a', 'b']
Configs not found for: a and b.

# for ['a', 'b', 'c']
Configs not found for: a,  b, and c.
```

In particular, the case of a single item looks like a bug, and in the case of 3 or more items the 2 spaces between `a,  b` looks a bit strange.

In any case, it would make sense to split the method, for example:

```
def _format_missing_message(self, missing):
    if missing:
        message = _oxford_comma(missing)
        self._tab_pane.currentWidget().update_status(
            "Configs not found for: {}.".format(message))

@staticmethod
def _oxford_comma(items):
    length = len(items)
    and_clause = '{} and '.format('' if length <= 2 else ',')
    return and_clause.join([',  '.join(items[:-1]), items[-1]])
```

This way it's easier to unit test the Oxford comma logic.

Finally, I think the method would be slightly easier to read like this:

```
def _oxford_comma(items):
    length = len(items)
    if length == 1:
        return items[0]
    if length == 2:
        return '{} and {}'.format(*items)
    return '{}, and {}'.format(', '.join(items[:-1]), items[-1])
```

### Count Duplicates

My only objection is the method name, `count_duplicates`. You are counting elements, not necessarily duplicates, and returning a map of `item => count` pairs. So for example `get_counts` would be more natural.

That's all I can pick on ;-)

Comment: Yeah the 1 item oxford comma is a bug. As for the double-space, it was a mistype :P Thanks for the input!

Comment: See [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/number-of-matching-elements-in-two-lists/51542#51542) for a more concise way to count the letter in a string.

Comment: @DarinDouglass nice to know, thanks for the reminder! (I keep forgetting that handy tool.)