# Number Of Matching Elements In Two Lists

Tags: python, optimization, performance, python-2.x

I have many sets of 2 strings. I'm trying to determine the number of matching elements in these 2 strings. The rules are if the strings share a common letter, that's a point, order does matter, but each letter in the first string can only match one of the letters in the second string. So in the strings `'aaaab'`, `'acccc'`, only `1` point is awarded because there is only one `'a'` to match in the second string. Here are a few examples:

```
aaabb  bbaaa  5
aabbb  bbbaa  5
aaabb  aabbb  4
aaabb  ccaaa  3
aaaaa  bbbbb  0
ababa  babab  4
aabcc  babaf  3
abcde  abfgh  2
bacde  abdgh  3
```

Hopefully that gets across how it works.

Here is the most efficient code I've been able to come up with, but its horribly convoluted. I hoping someone could think of something better.

```
def Score(guess, solution):
    guess = list(guess)
    solution = list(solution)
    c = 0
    for g in guess:
        if g in solution and g != "_":
            c += 1
            solution[solution.index(g)] = "_"
    return c
```

Surely this isn't the best way to do this, but I haven't been able to figure anything else out. I tried creating an algorithm with `Counter` and doing `guess&solution`, which worked, but ended up being way slower. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your code does not work

Comment: I think your examples don't much your algo description ...

Comment: The code does work, unless you got the earliest revision of the post. But I fixed that pretty quickly after I posted. The examples are fixed. I didn't run them through my code I just tried to give some examples to help understand the logic. Thanks for noticing though.

Comment: In python, functions are lowercase, capitalization is reserved for classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have updated your examples, you can write some code to ensure the code we are about to write works properly :

```
def main():
    """Main function"""
    assert Score('aaabb', 'bbaaa') == 5
    assert Score('aabbb', 'bbbaa') == 5
    assert Score('aaabb', 'aabbb') == 4
    assert Score('aaabb', 'ccaaa') == 3
    assert Score('aaaaa', 'bbbbb') == 0
    assert Score('ababa', 'babab') == 4
    assert Score('aabcc', 'babaf') == 3
    assert Score('abcde', 'abfgh') == 2
    assert Score('bacde', 'abdgh') == 3
```

Now, the main issue in your code is that we are performing complicated (dirty?) string logic and checking many times if some letter is in a list. The real solution is to count letters in both string. Each letter will count for n points where n is the minimum between the number of times it appears in string 1 and the number of times it appears in string 2.

Using `Counter`, you can write this :

from collections import Counter

```
def Score(guess, solution):
    g = Counter(guess)
    s = Counter(solution)
    n = 0
    for l,c in g.iteritems():
        n+=min(c, s[l])
    return n
```

Abusing generator expressions, you can also write this :

```
def Score(s1, s2):
    c = Counter(s2)
    return sum(min(n, c[l]) for l,n in Counter(s1).iteritems())
```

Comment: I don't think that's abusing generator expressions, your second snippet is exactly how it should be done IMO (I'd just use more meaningful names).

Comment: Agree! I just try to give the different steps leading to the solution and giving the name of the principle behind it. I'm glad you like it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` you easily get the counts of each character in the strings:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_count(string):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for char in string;
        counts[char] += 1

    return count
```

Find the counts for each string and pass the `defaultdict`s to your score function. Then its as simple as taking the minimum value for each `key` in the `defaultdict`s:

```
def get_score(dict_one, dict_two):
    score = 0
    for key in dict_one:
        score += min(dict_one[key], dict_two[key])

    return score
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>>get_score(get_count('aaabb'), get_count('bbaaa'))
5
>>>get_score(get_count('ababa'), get_count('babab'))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer but too big for a comment and it seems important to let you know that your examples do not work - at least not on my config.

Here's what I have (string1, string2, actual result, expected result)

```
aaabb bbaaa
5 5
aabbb bbbaa
5 4
aaabb aabbb
4 4
aaabb ccaaa
3 3
aaaaa bbbbb
0 0
ababa babab
4 4
aabcc babaf
3 3
abcde abfgh
2 2
bacde abdgh
3 2
```

Comment: You're right, I just created examples off the top of my head, I've fixed them in the examples. But the code works. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the following code

```
def count_score(guess, solution):
    score = 0
    solution = list(solution)
    for g in guess:
        try:
            solution.pop(solution.index(g))
            score += 1
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return score
```

If the current char from guess (g) is not found by index an `ValueError Exception` is thrown.

Comment: Using exception handling is generally considered bad practice. It breaks logical flow, and in some cases can slow down your program.

Comment: Correct @BenVlodgi. However, as some food for thought, a classic Python axium is `its easier to ask for forgiveness than permission`. Essentially, in some cases its bette to use `try-except` than many possible if-statements.