# Comma formatted list printer

Tags: python, performance, formatting, iteration

I'm working on a list **practice project** from the book *"Automate the Boring Stuff with Python"* which asks for this:

> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a
> string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with *and*
> inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam
> list to the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'.
> But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to
> it. Be sure to test the case where an empty list [] is passed to your
> function.

So far I've come up with this:

```
def comma_code(iterable):
    '''
    Function that loops through every value in a list and prints it with a comma after it,
    except for the last item, for which it adds an "and " at the beginning of it.
    Each item is str() formatted in output to avoid concatenation issues.

    '''
    for i, item in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == len(iterable)-1 and len(iterable) != 1: # Detect if the item is the last on the list and the list doesn't contain only 1 item (BONUS) 
            print('and ' + str(iterable[-1]))           # Add 'and ' to the beginning
        elif len(iterable) == 1:                        # BONUS: If list contains only 1 item,
            print('Just ' + str(iterable[-1]))          # replace 'and ' with 'Just '
        else:                                           # For all items other than the last one
            print(str(iterable[i]) + ',', end=" ")      # Add comma to the end and omit line break in print
```

There's heavy commenting because I'm fairly new and I'm trying to leave everything as clear as possible for my future self.

Now I wonder if there's a better way of doing this and also (subjective question) if there is something in my code that I should change for better readability and/or style. As I said, I'm fairly new and I would like to pick good coding practices from the beginning.

These are a couple of lists I ran through the function:

```py
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
bacon = [3.14, 'cat', 11, 'cat', True]
enty = [1]
```

And this is the working output:

```
apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
3.14, cat, 11, cat, and True
Just 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"returns a string"* - You're not doing that at all.

Comment: Care to explain? Is it because i'm printing the output rather than returning it?

Comment: Well... yeah...

Comment: I fixed it, I just didn't know how to print a "return" value. Thanks for pointing it out, my logic was faulty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## An alternate approach

- The routine is same for **all** types of inputs, **except** for when the `len(list) == 1`. This is why we can use a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)  to simplify the routine, and then a simple `if` statement to work with the exception

```py
def comma_code(iterable):
    result = ', '.join(str(value) for value in iterable[:-1])
    return f"{result}, and {iterable[-1]}"
```

Now, since we have to deal with a special case, an if-statement can work

```py
def comma_code(iterable):
    if not iterable: return None
    if len(iterable) == 1: return f"Just {iterable[0]}"

    result = ', '.join(str(value) for value in iterable[:-1])
    return f"{result}, and {iterable[-1]}"
```

The question hasn't stated **what** to do if the size of the container is `0`, hence I have just returned `None`. As stated by @Stef in the comments, you can also return an empty string which is just `''`. 
I would prefer `None` as it becomes easy to trace back if an issue occurred.
 Moreover, you can also design a simple function that would check if the container is empty. If it is then the function can print a custom warning which can help you in debugging your code

## Explanation

```py
result = ', '.join(str(value) for value in iterable[:-1])
```

This is called a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), we're basically appending `str(value) + ', '` for every `value` in `iterable`.
 `iterable[:-1]` so that we only iterate till the second last element. 
to be fully verbose, `:-1` says *everything in `iterable` up till the last element*

---

Comment: A gift introducing the _generator_ & _f-strings_ and explaining so gentle  Applied **pythonic conciseness** like a pro.

Comment: `result = ', '.join(str(value) for value in iterable[:-1])`
Is this applying the concept of list comprehension? I'm familiar with f-string formatting and understand what generator code does for memory optimization, but i'm yet to recognize easily the format for list comprehensions.

Comment: I tried this, it works great and it's really compact. I only had to figure out how to print the function return values. Thanks.

Comment: However, I just found an issue in the format. Output shows a comma after every item, including the next to last so it ends up looking like "Item[1], Item[2], ... Item[-2] **,** and Item[-1]". Simply removing  the ',' after {result} in `return f"{result}, and {iterable[-1]}"` seems to fix the issue (In case you want to update your code).

Comment: @VaneyRio Hey, sorry for the late reply, don't you need a `,` before `and`? That's how I remember my English to be, if not its simply to remove it, as you said just remove it from the f-string

Comment: @VaneyRio Do you still have any doubts? I can make a little chat room to clarify anything

Comment: Instead of `iterable[:-1]` which creates a copy, you could also call [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) like this: `islice(iterable, len(iterable) - 1)`

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Never knew about that! Thanks for the suggestion, but wouldn't a simple `[]` be worth the cost for better readability?

Comment: @AryanParekh indeed there's a trade-off of readability, memory and speed. Also a plain `[:-1]` slicing will be faster for small lists / tuples. There is also [`take_nth`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.take_nth) from the [pytoolz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toolz/) / [cytoolz](https://pypi.org/project/cytoolz/) package, which can be used like this: `take_nth(len(iterable) - 1, iterable)`. Anyway, changes like should be made only after some profiling / benchmarking.

Comment: The text of the question says "Be sure to test the case where an empty list [] is passed to your function." but this answer says "Note that I am assuming len(iterable) is always >= 1".

Comment: @Stef My bad, I didn't read it thoroughly, I will edit the answer now.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I believe unless one is coding for something like an embedded system where memory is not free, it's not a problem! :)

Comment: `if len(iterable) == 0: return iterable` Why not return `""` instead? The user might be surprised if the function returns something which isn't a string.

Comment: @Stef Well, it wasn't mentioned in the question. I think it should just return `None`. But again, the question says nothing about handling the Exception, I edited it anyway

Comment: "Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with *and* inserted before the last item." It's pretty explicit in that sentence that the return value should be a string. "all the items" if there are no items means no items. Thus an empty string. However, the python code showed as the answer adds the word "Just" in case of one element, which isn't mentioned in the text of the question.

Comment: @VaneyRio Your question stipulates that there must be a comma "," before "and"... why are you making it an issue that this answer conforms with the task specification?

Comment: @Stef I'm won't comment on that since that should be clarified by the OP. Otherwise, I would very much prefer returning `None` compared to an empty string. It's alright! There is absolutely no point in arguing further :)

Answer (score 5):

#### Well done

First I like your attitude "for the future me". Keep that clean-coding practice. It will truely help.

#### Handle edge cases aside

I would extract the *junction-part* (", ", " and ") and particularly the single case ("Just "):

```py
def print_joined(iterable):
  # in unlikely case of nothing (fail-fast)
  if len(iterable) == 0:
    # raise an error or print sorry instead of returning silently
    return
  # special intro if single
  elif len(iterable) == 1:
    print('Just ' + str(iterable[0]))
    return

  ## multiples concatenated
  for i, item in enumerate(iterable):
      join = ', ' # default separator

  ## multiples concatenated
  joined_items = ''
  for i, item in enumerate(iterable):
      junction = ', ' # default separator

      if i == len(iterable)-2:
        junction = ' and ' # special separator before last
      elif i == len(iterable)-1:
        junction = ''  # last item ends without separator

      joined_items += str(item) + junction  # you defined item on loop, so use it

  print(joined_items)
```

This alternative is just making the different cases clear.
Although a bit verbose  and not very *pythonic* (no generator, no template based string-formatting used), it focuses on **robustness**.

To give the lengthy method body structure and separate different parts for **readability** I inserted empty lines (vertical spacing) - individual preference of style.

All edge-cases are caught in the beginning in order to **return/fail fast** (avoid obsolete loop). This is best-practice when it comes to validation.

The **core purpose** can be **easily read** from the **last line** (the return line): printing items joined.
The side amenities like case-based junction strings are put *literally* as **topping**.
Refinement can be introduced in later iterations (**extensibility**), depending on your experience, e.g.:

- enhanced formatting/printing (using Python's convenience functions)
- returning a string (making the function a formatter, independent from output interface)
- parameterize junction-strings (for customisation/localisation instead of hard-coded)

#### Usability: Grammar for using comma before `and` in lists

I wondered about the comma before `and` and did research.
The phenomenon called [*serial comma* or *Oxford comma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma), is described in the *Grammarly Blog* post [Comma Before And](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-and/). It essentially says:

- You usually put a comma before and when it’s connecting two independent clauses.
- It’s almost always optional to put a comma before and in a list.
- You should not use a comma before and if you’re only mentioning two qualities.

Since I assume the function should **list pure items** (names, nouns, verbs) - not clauses - I implemented a simple `and` (without *serial comma*) to also handle 2 items grammatically correctly.

Thus as long as the different junctions can't be parameterized yet, you should clarify (implicitly) applied junction-rules in a comment (doc-string).

Comment: I tried this because I like the idea of testing for errors before computing anything else, however, there's a problem with this code.
Last item (iterable[-1]) shows in the output as:
'iterable[-1] and' rather than 'and iterable[-1]'.

Inverting the print statement also changes the order of the ',' to the beginning of every item printed.

Comment: @VaneyRio Thanks! I forgot to test my solution. Now fixed and updated the code. Note: comparison with 0-based index `i` to check for last `i == len(iterable)-1`.

Comment: Did some grammar research on _Oxford comma_ and SO suggests related review on [Refactor Oxford Comma function (and other functions)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51238)